# Building a large function that appends together multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a pretty extensive dataframe that I know is going to require building some sort of function or loop. I'll try to walk this through step by step.

First step is entering your credentials, which I believe are needed for this. It's using the Instagram API, so to make this reproducible, you will need to enter your Instagram username/password (Or you can just make an account specifically for this, whatever works best). It also builds a dataframe for the five accounts we're going to be getting information from.

```
from instagram_private_api import Client, ClientCompatPatch
from operator import itemgetter
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests

user_name = 'XXXX'
password = 'XXXXX'

api = Client(user_name, password)

players = [['lpspeggy31', '2534051587'], ['henrydavis32', '237423618'], ['nickgonzales_21', '198603777'], ['quinn_priester', '196485521'], ['mikeburr0ws', '55787938']]
player_df = pd.DataFrame(players, columns=['username', 'userId'])
```

The next step is going to be pulling a list of each of their followers. The code posted below allows you to do it one at a time, but obviously we're doing multiple `userId`'s from the `player_df` DF we created. You will notice there are multiple hardcoded lines that we want to change to make it applicable with the data moving through the function: `follow_username`, `following_userid`, and `get_followers`.

```
 # Followers (while for pagination)
def followers_users(userid_instagram):
    followers = []
    combinacao = []
    
    results = api.user_followers(userid_instagram, rank_token=api.generate_uuid())
    followers.extend(results.get('users', []))
    next_max_id = results.get('next_max_id')

    while next_max_id:
        results = api.user_followers(userid_instagram, rank_token=api.generate_uuid(), max_id=next_max_id)
        followers.extend(results.get('users', []))
        next_max_id = results.get('next_max_id')
        
    userid = [followers[i]['pk'] for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    full_names = [followers[i]['full_name'] for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    usernames = [followers[i]['username'] for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    profile_pic_url = [followers[i]['profile_pic_url'] for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    followers_text = ['follower' for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    following_username = ['lpspeggy31' for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    following_userid = ['2534051587' for i in range(0,len(followers))]
    
    combinacao.extend([list(i) for i in zip(userid, full_names,
                                            usernames, profile_pic_url, followers_text,
                                            following_username, following_userid)])
    combinacao = sorted(combinacao, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=False)
    return(combinacao)

get_followers = followers_users('2534051587')
followers = pd.DataFrame(get_followers, columns = ['userID' , 'Full Name', 'username', 'Profile Picture', 'Type', 'following_username', 'following_userid']) 
followers
```

So from this we want to create a dataframe using all five of the `username`'s and `userId`'s from `player_df` and all the results appended together. So all five of those accounts have roughly 50K combined followers, though the total number of final rows in that dataframe I would expect to be significantly less since I don't believe it pulls accounts set to private.

Once that's complete, we move on to the final and most data heavy step, pulling the photo information for ALL of the five users follower list. So it will basically go through all the followers created from the code above, with their usernames plugging in to the `get_photos = photo_information('lpspeggy31')`  line.

```
from collections import Counter
import datetime

# Creating dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Extract photos information
def photo_information(username_insta):
    
    # Initialize the lists
    likes=[]
    comments_count=[]
    url=[]
    teste=[]
    data_foto=[]
    latitudelista = []
    longitudelista = []
    locationlista = []
    caption_photo=[]
    curtidores_username=[]
    curtidores_fullname=[]
    username_lista=[]

    # Extract all photos information (while for pagination)
    request = api.username_feed(username_insta)
    teste.extend(request.get('items'))
    next_max_id = request.get('next_max_id')
    while next_max_id:
        request = api.username_feed(username_insta, max_id=next_max_id)
        next_max_id = request.get('next_max_id')
        teste.extend(request.get('items'))
    

    # Número de likes em todas as fotos
    for i in range(0,len(teste)):
        # username
        username_lista.append(username_insta)

        # Date
        if 'taken_at' in teste[i]:
            data_foto.append(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(teste[i]['taken_at']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        else:
            data_foto.append('-')

        # Caption text photo
        if ('caption' in teste[i]) and (not teste[i]['caption'] is None):
            titulo_foto=str(teste[i]['caption']['text'])
            caption_photo.append(titulo_foto)
        else:
            caption_photo.append('-')

        # Number of likes
        if 'like_count' in teste[i]:
            likes.append(teste[i]['like_count'])
        else:
            likes.append('-')

        # Comments count
        if 'comment_count' in teste[i]:
            comments_count.append(teste[i]['comment_count'])
        else:
            comments_count.append('-')

        # Latitude, longitude, location
        if 'lat' in teste[i]:
            latitudelista.append(teste[i]['lat'])
        else:
            latitudelista.append('-')
            
        if 'lng' in teste[i]:    
            longitudelista.append(teste[i]['lng'])
        else:
            longitudelista.append('-')
            
            
        if 'location' in teste[i]:   
            locationlista.append(teste[i]['location']['city'])
        else:
            locationlista.append('-')

        # URL
        if 'carousel_media' not in teste[i]:
            url.append(teste[i]['image_versions2']['candidates'][0]['url'])
        else:
            url.append(teste[i]['carousel_media'][0]['image_versions2']['candidates'][0]['url'])
    
    combinacao21=[]
    combinacao21.extend([list(i) for i in zip(data_foto, username_lista,
                                        likes, comments_count, caption_photo, locationlista, latitudelista, longitudelista, url)])
    combinacao21 = sorted(combinacao21, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=False)
    return(combinacao21)

    
get_photos = photo_information('lpspeggy31')  
photos = pd.DataFrame(get_photos, columns = ['Data' , 'Username', 'Likes', 'Comments', 'Title Photo', 'Location', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'URL']) 
photos['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(photos['Data'])
photos
```

So the final dataframe will be the photo information for all of the accounts who follow the five original accounts.

Comment: This is not a tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: Okay whatever. Don't think I'm doing that, but that's your opinion I guess. Not really sure how you can read a post where I've written like 95% of the code already and think that I'm asking people to do my work for me. I think I posted it in a way that is extremely reproducible. Hopefully someone else takes a stab at answering it, you don't have to, and you certainly don't need to insert your (rude) opinion if you're not actually answering it.

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me what the question is... Could you elaborate on what you are looking to improve in your code?

Comment: I agree with @SultanOrazbayev, while there is lot's of code, the question doesn't seem to convey a clear description of what the OP wants.